# Mocking a static method with generic parameter

Tags: java, junit, powermock

i am trying to mock a static method with sigature

```
 public static <T extends Object> T get( String name, Class<T> i )
  {
    return null
  }
```

and i am using PowerMockito, and below is my expected code

```
PowerMockito.when(ClassName.class, "get", "name", Class.class).thenReturn("Hi");
```

but its throwing

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name 'get' with parameter types: [ java.lang.String, java.lang.Class ]
```

Can anyone plz give the clue how to mock this using powermockito

Comment: Does this work for **static**, but **not generic** method?

Comment: @ginz That shouldn't make a difference, the method under test will have the signature `public static Object get(String name, Class i)` when compiled anyway due to type erasure.

Comment: yes, tested with only string param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to first tell Powermockito what class contains *static* methods that you want to mock by:

   ```
   PowerMockito.mockStatic(Classname.class);
   ```
2. Then you can mock the method using:

   ```
   PowerMockito.when(Classname.get("name", Clas.class)).thenReturn("Hi");
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't the second part still be `PowerMockito.when(ClassName.class, "get", "name", Class.class).thenReturn("Hi");`?