# Mocking android.os.Build.MODEL

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to create a test using Mockito/PowerMockito in which we use the value from `android.os.Build.MODEL`. I've tried using:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({android.os.Build.class})
public class Test {
  @Before
  public void init() {
    PowerMockito.spy(android.os.Build.class);
    PowerMockito.doReturn("model").when(Build.class, "getString", "ro.product.model");
  }
}
```

because I saw that `Device.MODEL` was making a call to the `private static String getString` method, but I get the following exception:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name 'getString' with parameter types: [ java.lang.String ] in class android.os.Build.
```

Is there any way to mock this variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702587/1697047 check this

Comment: doesn't change anything if I use `PowerMockito.mockStatic(android.os.Build.class);` instead of `spy`

Answer (score 7):

```
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(Build.class,"MODEL", "Value-You-Want-Model-To-Be");
```

I like robolectric for that sort of thing, you'd use the above call to mock out the field